Proving $ 16a^2+20\sqrt{2}a+15=\sqrt{11(a^{12}-1)}+\sqrt{2(a^{12}-4)}$ for a specific algebraic number $a$
Let $F=\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt{2})$ and let $a$  be the real root of $f(x) =x^3-2x-\sqrt{2}\in F[x] $. Using Cardano's   approach one can show that $$a=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\sqrt{\frac{11} {54}}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\sqrt{\frac{11} {54}}}\tag{1} $$ One can show with some effort that $f(x) $ has no roots in $F$ and hence is irreducible over $F$ and then $[F(a) :F] =3$. And hence any rational function of $a$ with coefficients in $F$ ie any member of $F(a) $ can be expressed as a quadratic polynomial in $a$ with coefficients in $F$.
Now the real number $a$ satisfies a mysterious identity $$16a^2+20\sqrt{2}a+15=\sqrt{11(a^{12}-1)}+\sqrt{2(a^{12}-4)}\tag{2}$$ which I am trying to prove and I have been thoroughly unsuccessful here.
I first proved that $$a^{12}=80a^2+96\sqrt{2}a+68$$ and using this expression I guessed that both $11(a^{12}-1)$ and $2(a^{12}-4)$ are perfect squares and tried to find their square roots as members of $F(a)$. Unfortunately nothing materialised here and the calculations seemed formidable because coefficients involved are not integers but rather algebraic integers of $F$ of the form $p+q\sqrt{2}$.
A brute force approach to prove $(2)$ involves squaring it two times and seems rather tedious. I have verified the identity numerically using the value $a=1.68501832$.
I am hoping that there is some smart way to do the calculations so that the identity is established without too much labor.

The origin of $a$ lies in the researches by Ramanujan and I will add a bit of related context here.
Let $n$ be a positive rational number and we define Ramanujan class invariant $$G_n=2^{-1/4}e^{\pi\sqrt{n}/24}\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}(1+e^{-(2i-1)\pi\sqrt{n}})\tag{3}$$ The number $a$ defined above is $a=G_{11}^2$ and is crucial in evaluation of certain expression in Ramanujan's Lost Notebook. I was trying to do the same evaluation and stumbled onto the indentity $(2)$.

Don't you prefer $$2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh
^{-1}\left(\frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{4}\right)\right)$$ for the real root ?

@ClaudeLeibovici: I am not sure if that form would help in proving the desired identity. But if that helps it would be nice to see a derivation.

The problem is greatly simplified if we observe that $a$ is of degree $6$ over rationals (ie $[\mathbb{Q} (a) :\mathbb{Q}] =6]$) and the minimal polynomial for $a$ over rationals is $$(x^3-2x-\sqrt{2})(x^3-2x+\sqrt{2})$$ or $$x^6-4x^4+4x^2-2$$ and hence $b=a^2$ is a root of $$g(x) =x^3-4x^2+4x-2\tag{1}$$ Next let us note that
\begin{align}
2(a^{12}-4)&=2(b^6-4)\notag\\
&=2((4b^2-4b+2)^2-4)\notag\\
&=2(16b^4+32b^2-32b^3-16b)\tag{2}\\
&=32b(b^3-2b^2+2b-1)\notag\\
&=32b(4b^2-4b+2-2b^2+2b-1)\notag\\
&=32b(2b^2-2b+1)\notag\\
&=16b(4b^2-4b+2)\notag\\
&=16b^4\notag
\end{align}
and hence $$\sqrt{2(a^{12}-4)}=4b^2=4a^4$$ Thus the identity to be proved is reduced to $$16a^2+20\sqrt{2}a+15=4a^4+\sqrt{11(a^{12}-1)}$$ or $$16a^2+20a(a^3-2a)+15-4a^4=\sqrt{11(a^{12}-1)}$$ or $$16b^2-24b+15=\sqrt{11(b^6-1)}$$ or $$256b^4+576b^2+225-768b^3-720b+480b^2=11(b^6-1)$$ Using $(2)$ this is equivalent to $$256b^4+1056b^2+225-768b^3-720b=11(16b^4+32b^2-32b^3-16b+3)$$ or $$256b^4+1056b^2+192-768b^3-720b=11(16b^4+32b^2-32b^3-16b)$$ Dividing by $16$ we see that this is equivalent to $$16b^4-48b^3+66b^2-45b+12=11(b^4-2b^3+2b^2-b)$$ or $$5b^4-26b^3+44b^2-34b+12=0$$ or $$5b(4b^2-4b+2)-26b^3+44b^2-34b+12=0$$ or $$-6b^3+24b^2-24b+12=0$$ which is true as it nothing but $-6g(b)$.
